# Selenium, minimizing repetitious code

Tags: java, selenium

The selenium tests I'm gonna be doing are basically based on three main steps, with different parameters. These parameters are passed in from a text file to the test. this allows easy completion of a test such as create three of "X" without writing the code to do the create three times in one test.

Imagine i have a test involving creating two of "X" and one of "Y". CreateX and CreateY are already defined in separate tests. Is there a nice way of calling the code contained in createX and createY from say, Test1?

I tried creating a class with the creates as seperate methods, but got errors on all the selenium.-anything-, ie every damn line. it goes away if i extend seleneseTestCase, but it seems that my other test classes wont import from a class that extends seleneseTestCase. I'm probably doing something idiotic but i might as well ask!

EDIT:
well for example, its gonna be the same setUp method for every test, so id like to only write that once... instead of a few hundred times...

```
public void ready() throws Exception 
{
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://localhost:9443/");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.setSpeed("1000");
    selenium.setTimeout("999999");
    selenium.windowMaximize();
}
```

thats gonna be used EVERYWHERE.
its in a class called reuseable. Id like to just call reuseable.ready(); from the tests SetUp... but it wont let me....

Comment: Post some code of what you already tried ?

Comment: You can use @Before for this. I'll write some code and show you.

Comment: but what i mean is the @before is gonna be the same for every test. So isnt it redundant to write the code in every test? it seems it'd be nicer for the @before to just be one line, a method call...

Comment: Take a look at my example code. The contents of the @Before only needs to be defined once then the JUnit runner will automatically run it before each test. If it's handy you can also use @After for selenium.stop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ExampleTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("setup");
    }

    public void someSharedFunction() {
        System.out.println("shared function");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test1");
        someSharedFunction();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("test2");
        someSharedFunction();
    }
}
```

The contents of the function after the @Before annotation is what will be executed before every test. **someSharedFunction()** is an example of a 'reusable' function. The code above will output the following:

```
setup
test1
shared function
setup
test2
shared function
```

Comment: sooo say i have a createX and createY tests already defined.... i can do 
//sidenote, im failing at commenting....

-->@before
-->call createX
-->call createY
-->@after

and it'l run the whole thing?

Comment: That comment was much prettier before i hit enter.... I knew there had to be some way to do what i wanted, this is my first time to see selenium/junit stuff at all.. thanks for the help!

Comment: @Test is used to denote each test. @Before will be run before each test. And @After is run after each test. Give it a go : )

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JUnit and trying out some of the tutorials on [junit.org](http://www.junit.org/). The problem you have described can be fixed using the `@Before` annotation on a method that performs this setup in a super class of your tests

Comment: In hindsight this is only part of my problem... I also reuse identical code throughout the @test parts. so I'd like to be able to have something like a spare class somewhere that holds these methods and can be called from within each test.

Comment: Create helper methods in the super class like createX and createY, which you can then call from any of your tests

Comment: ahh, test extends helper. helper extends seleneseTestcase :/ of course. I got confused when i tried to extend two things. Thanks for the help all of ye